# Securing actions in Grails 2 rc3

Tags: grails, spring-security

In Config.groovy I decided to secure all actions that have to do with editing content like so:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
        '/admin/**' : ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],

        '/*/create/**' : ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
        '/*/save/**' : ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
        '/*/update/**' : ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
        '/*/edit/**' : ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],

        '/contactUs/create/new_message.html' : ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
        '/**':               ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY']


]
```

... just wonder if this is sufficient or am I asking for trouble? Or what would be better/proper way of securing all 'create,save,update,edit' actions in all controllers?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just two thoughts...

- what about deleting objects? I guess with this config, everybody can delete anonymously
- and that brings me to my second point: you implement security with a black list (what are the controllers and actions which should be not accessible unauthenticated), but you should implement security through a white list (what are the controllers and actions which are accessible unauthenticated). The second aproach would have avoided the 'delete' problem.

PS: I use shiro, so I have no experience with spring security and don't know how to whitelist controllers and actions.