# Which Security Framework to use for Grails application?

Tags: grails, spring-security, security, grails-plugin

I spent a couple of weeks trying to figure out what solution I should bring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584671/access-control-role-and-permission-in-grails) I posted. Since I couldn't find a full documentation for Shiro-Grails integration, I am looking for some other framework (like Spring) to secure our lightweight web based Grails application.

The application is couple of months old and it is not a huge application. Not more 20 persistent classes. However, I believe it will grow up soon. But, security is not implemented yet and I want to make sure that I will find the best security framework (for me the best might include: free source, well documented, easy to integrate with Grails, extensible, and last but not least more secured).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Steve is right - it is between SpringSecurity and Shiro.

I am using Shiro - the documentation isn't as good as it could be, but the *-Permissions are great.

You grant permission by specifying `"controller:action"` tuples. And you can use lists and wildcards:

```
"*:list,show" //everything read-only
"book:*"      //everything allowed on the book class
"*:*"         //admin
```

As a result, you have all permissions as whitelist (based on controller:action) in one file.

What I've seens so far for SpringSecurity is that you often base the permissions on URLs - that's IMHO an easy way to miss to secure a controller or action. see [Securing actions in Grails 2 rc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499290/securing-actions-in-grails-2-rc3/) for example :-)

PS: if anybody knows how this kind of *-Permission is done in SpringSecurity, please post a comment!

Comment: Agreed - the two killer features in Shiro are permissions and distributed sessions.  Simplicity is also a selling point.

Comment: Thanks Ralf for your comment. Well, I agree with what you guys said. However, the problem I am facing is, I believe, just a simple problem but, because of lack of documentation, I wasted my time for nothing. In case if you haven't looked, here is my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584671/access-control-role-and-permission-in-grails . Do you have any clue why its giving all the grants?

Answer (score 5):

The standard Grails security framework is Spring Security. Check out the [docs](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/)

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much it is between [SpringSecurity](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) and [Shiro](http://www.grails.org/plugin/shiro).

Spring Security seems to be becoming the standard for Grails as doelleri said, it should provide anything you could ever wish for and is [well documented](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/index.html) and designed.  Shiro I found to be functionally on a par for the basic security tasks but I feel the docs let it down in comparison.  There is a plugin (now not being maintained) called Nimble that uses Shiro as a basis, [Nimble](http://www.grails.org/plugin/nimble) is powerful and provides a lot of functions such as user management GUI out-of-the-box.

I just started with Spring Security for a new project and am now finding it very powerful and simple to use, and am glad I made the change.  But in the end it is up to your project/organisational needs.

Comment: I still do have the chance to choose Spring over Shiro. Our application is just a simple data management system. It is not a huge system for now.

Comment: MatX a helpful discussion on this just came up in [Grails user](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Security-plugins-td4275329.html)